# how do I see my phone through Android Studio?

Tags: android

Good afternoon. I'm trying to see the folders of an application and if possible to change the attributes of it, and for that I wanted to know if it is possible to connect the phone in the android studio to see the contents of the phone, the sdks and similar things to browse the folders to be able to modify and access content.
thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

After enable developer tools on your phone, connecting it to the computer and allowing Android Debug Bridge (ADB), you should see the device listed at Android Studio, just like any other emulator.

[image]

On the bottom right of android studio there's a tool called Device File Explorer. You can use it to explore the contents of the device.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1hpo.png

Comment: I am very, very thankful about this! I appreciate your answer, will try and return here after it, have an awesome day!